# Why does enable_if with true value seem to work differently than putting void in directly?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm getting an ambiguity error when I try to instantiate my templated functor with partial specializations.  Foo and Bar below are identical except for `Foo`'s `enable_if_t` is replaced with just `void` in `Bar`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class Enable = void>
  struct Foo;

template<class T>
struct Foo<T, enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>>{
    void operator()(){
    }
};


template<class T, class...Rest>
struct Foo<std::vector<T, Rest...>>
{
    void operator()(){
      cout<<"In vector"<<endl;
    }
};

template<class T, class Enable = void>
  struct Bar;

template<class T>
struct Bar<T, void>{
    void operator()(){
    }
};


template<class T, class...Rest>
struct Bar<std::vector<T, Rest...>>
{
    void operator()(){
      cout<<"In vector"<<endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
   // Foo<vector<int>> f; // <== this fails with the error below:
    Bar<vector<int>> b;
}
```

If the commented out line is brought back in, I get the following

```
prog.cc:46:22: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'Foo<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, void>'
    Foo<vector<int>> f;
                     ^
prog.cc:10:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >]
struct Foo<T, enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>>{
       ^
prog.cc:17:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = int, Rest = <std::__1::allocator<int>>]
struct Foo<std::vector<T, Rest...>>
```

Can someone explain what is happening, please?  I thought `enable_if_t<SOME_TRUE_VALUE>`'s type was `void`, so I don't understand why the are behaving differently.

Also, if anyone can provide a resource for an "easy" description of the process used to select between viable partial specializations (i.e. not the spec), that would be awesome.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you detail the lines 90.8 and 739.8 => if the specialization is ambiguous, then what are the two corresponding case the compiler is finding?

Comment: The two it's finding are the ones listed in the compiler error message.  -- or I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'll try to put together a testcase

Comment: Full compilable test case added, also here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NZtHSeTNcs9cCc4L

Comment: Neither of your specializations is more specialized than the other. Thus when both match, there is an ambiguity. OTOH when you use void, the second specialization matches anything at all, and so the first one becomes strictly more specialized.

Comment: but why does Bar work when I just say void?

Comment: @n.m. I thought that since enable_if_t's type was void that there wouldn't be any difference.   Do you have a source on the selection rules you can share?  Preferably not the spec, but I'll take anything.

Comment: Is the `vector` specialization for `Foo` well formed? It only has one real template parameter, I don't think that is valid when the unspecialized one has two. Unless the default second one still applies?

Comment: I don't know of other sources, but intuitively the rules are very simple. In your case, the first specialization matches any vector and the second one matches any container of non-pointers. So when you give them a type which is both of these things, there's no reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @JamesRoot The number of arguments doesn't matter.

Comment: @n.m. You didn't mean "container of non-pointer", you meant "any non-pointer" right?  But I guess neither of those are "anything", so they're both more specific than "anything".  Is it pretty much just: exact > sort of > anything?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, any non-pointer. I misread it. I imagined there's a value_type somewhere in there. It doesn't matter that they are more specific than "anything". We're trying to decide between the two, not between "anything" and something else. If you think one should be preferred, explain which one, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n.m.'s answer from the comments:

Neither of your specializations is more specialized than the other. Thus when both match, there is an ambiguity. OTOH when you use void, the second specialization matches anything at all, and so the first one becomes strictly more specialized.